# Vue 1.x/2.x: Get vue-router path url from a $route object

Tags: mvvm, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

As we know, we can use `vue-route` to wrap some route paths.

```
<!-- vue 1.x -->
<a v-link="{name: 'route_name', params: {id: 1}}"></a>
```

And in vue2:

```
<!-- vue 2.x -->
<router-link :to="{name: 'route_name', params: {id: 1}}"></router-link>
```

And now, I want to display a link url for the user to copy, so I wonder if there is a way to return the absolute path url from a route object? It seemed the docs did not mention that.

For example, I want:

```
<template>
  <label>Copy the address</label>
  <input value="url" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
      url() {
        const route = {name: 'route_name', params: {id: 1}};
        // !! The bellow shows what I may want.
        return this.$router.getLink(route);
      },
    }.
  };
</script>
```

Is there such a method?

Comment: I use https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync and then in components which need `path` I have computed property for that. Simple, straight forward solution.

Comment: There is the `$route.path` that would return absolute path for current route - https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html

Comment: @MU, I don't need the current path, I want the specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the Vue#1.0 solution:

Passing a route object like:

`const route = {name: 'route_name', params: {...}, query: {...}}`

to the method: `vm.$router.stringifyPath` returns the url path.

Then we can use the path to generate an `href` url.

But we also need to know what the router system mode is, so:

```
export default {
  methods: {
    getUrlFromRoute(route) {
      const vm = this;
      let path = vm.$router.stringifyPath(route);
      if (vm.$router.mode === 'hash') {
        if (vm.$router.history.hashbang) {
          path = '!' + path;
        }
        path = '#' + path;
      }
      // finally we add the absolute prefix before that
      if (path[0] === '#') {
        // hash mode join
        path = location.origin + location.pathname 
             + (location.query||'') + path;
      } else if(path[0] === '/') {
        // absolute path
        path = location.origin + path;
      } else {
        // relative path
        path = location.origin + location.pathname.replace(/\/[^\/]+$/, '/') + path;
      }
      return path;
    }
  }
};
```

Now we are free to share the link to somewhere else.

Answer (score 39):

For future people looking to do this

I believe this is the Vue 2.x way

```
var path = this.$router.resolve({name: 'SomePath', params: {id: 1}}).href
```

then if you want the full url you would do

```
var fullUrl = window.location.origin + "/" + path
```

Answer (score 4):

In Vue 2.0  maybe you can try my way: `this.$route.path` can get the URL path without domain. For example: `http://localhost:8000/#/reg` only gets the `/reg` part; the domain part you can get it easily outside the VueRouter. BTW: after creating `const router = new VueRouter ...`, you can get the URL by using `router.history.current.path;`. This method can get the URL like `/reg` too.

Comment: Excellent idea, I've never thought about creating another router instance, thank you!

Answer (score -3):

My previous answer has been deleted...

I use https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync and then in components which need `path` I have computed property for that. Simple, straight forward solution.

In your entry point, usually `main.js` you have to place:

```
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import store from './vuex/store' // vuex store instance
import router from './router' // vue-router instance

sync(store, router) // done.
```

and then in your component which needs `path` you have to have, of course in `<script>`:

```
computed: {
  path () {
    return store.state.router.path
  }
}
```